# error in building the hand tracking example of mediapipe

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, bazel, mediapipe

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to run handtracking example in the mediapipe package and when I run the building command using bazel I get the error below

```
ERROR: /home/mahtab/mediapipe/mediapipe/util/BUILD:127:11: C++ compilation of rule '//mediapipe/util:annotation_renderer' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 60 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 60 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
mediapipe/util/annotation_renderer.cc: In function 'int mediapipe::{anonymous}::ClampThickness(int)':
mediapipe/util/annotation_renderer.cc:43:10: error: 'clamp' is not a member of 'std'
   return std::clamp(thickness, 1, kMaxThickness);
          ^~~
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.912s, Critical Path: 2.56s
INFO: 154 processes: 150 internal, 4 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: `std::clamp` is a feature of c++17. gcc 11 makes that version the default. I think you should be able to add `--copt -std=c++17` to get it to build on older gcc versions.

Comment: There's a listed issue on the project for this - https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1811